# How to download PDF file using PUPPETEER after form submit? NodeJS | PUPPETEER

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless

I've been trying to download a PDF file using headless chrome. What I got to do is send a form with some info, on form submit it should download a PDF. How do I save this PDF? 
Obs: I'm using NodeJS as the framework.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not know exactly how the pdf is downloaded but I think you can use the following.

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: '/home/me/stuff'});
```

And then check for the file to be in the directory specified in the downloadPath property.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello, when I tried this on a Mac OS it worked perfectly, but in a Windows machine it didn't, any suggestions?

Comment: @BenjamínVázquez for windows you'd use a path like 'c:\\path\\to\\folder' instead of '/path/to/folder'