# Open a tab and run script

Tags: javascript

Below doesn’t work:

```
window.open(‘javascript:{do something here}’)
```

Some security error and asking for unsafe-inline keywordenter code here

I need to open a new window and navigate to a url and find a button and click it.

All i have are urls(hundreds of em) I’m looping and using promises for each url. The problem is the script doesn’t work because the page is reloaded as the link is clicked. Therefore it needs to be opened in new tab then I can run the script (of clicking button to download) as the link is opened.

```
var lk=[
  {
    "key": "www.someurl.com",
    "value": "somefile"
  },
  {
    "key": "someurl",
    "value": "somefilename"
  }];
p=Promise.resolve();
for(i=0;i<lk.length;i++){
  p=p.then(new Promise(_=>{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = lk[i].value;
    link.href = lk[i].key;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        _();
    },30000);
  }));
  console.log('Completed '+i);
}
```

Above script stops working as page is reloaded on link.click() in chrome console

I tried puppeteer, it has download issues. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to run the javascript in the current or new tab?

Comment: On opening of a new tab

Comment: have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428808/how-to-download-pdf-file-using-puppeteer-after-form-submit-nodejs-puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers isolate JavaScript code running on different origins (an origin is the combination of protocol, domain and port). While you can open a page on a different origin (by redirecting, opening a new window or adding a frame on the current page), you can't directly interact with it. So it's impossible for code on one page to open a different page and click on the button on that page.

The only way to work around this in a browser is to write a browser extension or user script. Browser extensions and user scripts are both higher privileged and able to interact with pages that are not under their control, but they need to be installed in the browser, and access to sites needs to be approved by the user (usually during installation).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I am creating another answer because you changed the question.

Don't create a link and then click on it, it will surely break the script due to reloading. instead, use ajax or https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch. these will call the given URL in the background. but then you will not be able to click the button.

So I would suggest, you create an iframe with the URL, and then maybe try clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

If this would be possible, it would be a huge security issue. You could use it to lure somebody to your page, then open their online bank in new tab and make a transaction for example.

If you have control over the page you are opening in the new tab then you could pass some query parameter and listen to that parameter in the new page and invoke some javascript if this parameter is set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe open the URL into an Iframe and then you can control its content. Something like this: [Control iframe content with javascript/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498725/control-iframe-content-with-javascript-html)

Then you can not only click the button, but you have complete access to its DOM. but make sure `X-Frame-Options` is not set for that website. otherwise, this option will not work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

and if that doesn't work: 
Then you may want to try:

1. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
2. https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/
3. https://www.cypress.io/

These tools are used for automated testing, but you can use these for your purpose.

These tools work like a human click on any button. They themselves open a browser, click on the button and let you know, or download the item or anything.

Comment: I’m using promises and upon clicking a link the page reloads and script doesn’t work

Comment: Okay, one main question: The URL you are trying to load, is it under your control or a third party?

Comment: If it's a third party, Try running the same script into the browser console and see if that works properly.

Comment: Third party, I’ve managed to scrape all the urls(download links) I’m trying to iterate using promises and save files

Comment: is your aim just to download all the resources? or you want to click on some button on that third party.
I might able to help if I get the idea of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I updated my answer again. Please let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: You guys don't have to mention it constantly, Stack overflow is informing us about the changes in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script that will trigger a button on a new tab, and that tab is under your control, then you can achieve this by supplying your tab with the following script:

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('my-button').click();
}
```

I would suggest using [Jquery Ready Function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) because it will be triggered once everything on the page is loaded.